# In VueRouter's Nested Routes Why define component at top level, when it is not utilized?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

What is the purpose of defining component 'User' at top level ? despite the fact that VueRouter does not consider it to render User component.

```
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
    import User from './views/User.vue'
    import UserHome from './views/UserHome.vue'
    import UserProfile from './views/UserProfile.vue'
    import UserPosts from './views/UserPosts.vue'
    
    export const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(),
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/users/:username',
          component: User,
          children: [
            // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
            // when /users/:username is matched
            { path: '', component: UserHome },
    
            // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
            // when /users/:username/profile is matched
            { path: 'profile', component: UserProfile },
    
            // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
            // when /users/:username/posts is matched
            { path: 'posts', component: UserPosts },
          ],
        },
      ],
    })
```

[example above](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-views-vue-router-4-examples-hl326?initialpath=%2Fusers%2Feduardo)

is referenced by VueRouter official documentation discussion
[Vuerouter Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-named-routes)
from the paragraph just above the heading "Nested Named Routes"...
Scroll up this referenced heading

Comment: Why do you think `User` is not being rendered?  Check the User.vue component in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-views-vue-router-4-examples-hl326?initialpath=/users/eduardo&file=/src/views/User.vue) you linked.  It's the root component of the route, the children components are all rendered in User.vue's `<router-view>`